# Improve flatten function in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, flatten

Given function needs some improvements:

```py
def flatten(d, parent_key=''):
    items = []
    for k, v in d.items():
        try:
            items.extend(flatten(v, '%s%s.' % (parent_key, k)).items())
        except AttributeError:
            items.append(('%s%s' % (parent_key, k), v))
    return dict(items)
```

I want to modify upper function.
That it also flattens lists:

```json
{'d': [1, 2, 3]}
```

To something like this:

```json
{'d[0]': 1, 'd[1]': 3, 'd[2]': 3}
```

**EDIT:**
This Code does it for me, but it's not as sleek as the first one any ideas for improvements?

```py
def flatten_dict(d):
    def items():
        for key, value in d.items():
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                for subkey, subvalue in flatten_dict(value).items():
                    yield key + "." + subkey, subvalue
            elif isinstance(value, list):
                for index, val in enumerate(value):
                    yield key + "[" + str(index) + "]" , value[index]
            else:
                yield key, value

    return dict(items())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
def flattern(dict_):
    result = {}
    for key in dict_:
        for i,j in enumerate(dict_[key]):
            result[key+'['+str(i)+']'] = j
    return result
```

call function like this,

```
In [40]: d
Out[40]: {'a': [1, 2, 3, 7], 'd': [1, 2, 3]}

In [41]: flattern(d)
Out[41]: {'a[0]': 1, 'a[1]': 2, 'a[2]': 3, 'a[3]': 7, 'd[0]': 1, 'd[1]': 2, 'd[2]': 3}
```

Comment: How would I implement it into the function?

Comment: The problem is I do not know the key in beforehand :s

Comment: doesnt work for me
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: @Skeec In which line ?

Comment: in this  for i,j in enumerate(dict_[key]):

Comment: Your input dictionary has some values which is an integer not list. The code expects a list. Your input also doesn't have any int on it. And what input you are giving to it ?

Comment: @Skeec What kind of input you are giving ?

Comment: Its fine now thank you I'll use the function in my editted post, because it returns the code the way I need it to be